# How to solve this join in EF

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, join

In the image below I have shown the looks of my tables. For the last couple of hours I am Trying to get the best solution for the Query I need but somehow I am running in circles of EF

[image]

I would need a collection of Roles with their Modules. Since there are roles which have no modules assigned it should be a left join. the collection should look like " {role, modules}" Role Should be a single object, and modules should be a collection of "Module" objects.

I tried doing it like this

```
var x = (from r in _context.Role
                     from rm in r.RoleModule.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join m in _context.Module on rm.ModuleID equals m.ID
                     select new { role= r, modules=rm }).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

As per suggestion by **lazyberezovsky** I made the partial class

```
public partial class Role
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Module> Modules { get { return RoleModule.Select(p => p.Module); } }
}
```

Works fine. Another issue of mine is,.... How can I make the "set" accessor.

**Edited**

Got this now and it works. But How can I access the collection of modules.

```
var x = (from r in _context.Role
                     join rm in _context.RoleModule on r.ID equals rm.RoleID into ps
                     from rm in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new { role=r, modules=rm.Module }).GroupBy(p => p.role).ToList();
```

* am using this in wpf to be set as datacontext*

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution will be defining navigation property for modules in your `Role` entity:

```
public class Role
{
   // ...
   public virtual ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will be able to do eager loading of roles with modules:

```
var roles = _context.Role.Include(r => r.Modules).ToList();
```

---

If your junction table is complex, then create navigation property of `ICollection<RoleModule>` type which holds both `Role` and `Module`. Query will look like:

```
var query = from r in context.Roles
            select new {
                 Role = r,
                 Modules = r.RoleModules.Select(rm => rm.Module)
            };
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not work. There is A table "RM" between roles and modules.

Comment: @user853710 EF handles junction tables pretty well. Is there more, than just ID of role and module in junction table?

Comment: @user853710 updated sample with left join and complex `RoleModule` entity

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting from Role, how about starting from the join table instead, if you have navigation properties in that class you can include them.

```
_context.RoleModule()
.Include("Role")
.Include("Module")
.Select(rm=> new {Role = rm.Role, Module = rm.Module}).ToList();
```

Comment: This way I will get a result from a join. I need a left join.